# Somando arrays (vetores) com métodos

Tags: java, array, métodos-estáticos

Tenho um exercício para fazer: criar um método onde o usuário insira os valores de 2 vetores, depois criar um método para somar os valores dos 2 vetores e por fim um terceiro método que mostre o novo vetor criado.

Segue o código criado até o momento:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Vetor2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] vetorA = new int[5];
        int[] vetorB = new int[5];
        inserirValores(vetorA, vetorB); 
        somaValores(vetorA, vetorB);
        int [] resultado = somaValores(vetorA, vetorB);
        criaNovoVetor(novoVetor);
    }

    public static void inserirValores(int[] a, int[] b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira o " + (i + 1) + "o valor do vetor A: "));
            b[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira o " + (i + 1) + "o valor do vetor B: "));
        }
    }

    public static int somaValores(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] vetorC = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            vetorC[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }
        return vetorC[5];
    }

    public static void criaNovoVetor(int [] novoVetor) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O novo vetor é: " + Arrays.toString(novoVetor));
    }
}
```

Estou com dois problemas:

1 - não consigo gravar o resultado da soma de um terceiro vetor (seja usando o próprio método somaValores, seja tentando passar para o método criaNovoVetor - tentei resolver só com 2 métodos primeiro porque achei que seria mais fácil, mas de qualquer forma preciso fazer com os três). Ocorre aquele erro *int cannot be converted to int[]*. Não entendo já que do lado esquerdo é um novo vetor e do direito a soma de 2 vetores, para mim os dois seriam int[].

2 - A linha return vetorC[5] estoura o array, não sei porque já que é do mesmo tamanho dos outros dois.

Comment: Qual a saída de `somaVetores`? Um inteiro com toda a soma dos 10 elementos ou então um vetor cujos 5 elementos são as somas da casa respectiva de `a` e `b`?

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro problema está nessa linha:

```
int [] resultado = somaValores(vetorA, vetorB);
```

O método `somaValores()` retorna `int` e não `int[]`.

Altere o tipo de retorno para `int[]` e ao invés de fazer `return vetorC[5];` faça `return vetorC;`

---

O segundo problema é por que os arrays são *zero based*. Isso significa que a primeira posição deles é `0` e não `1`, ou seja, um array de 5 posições não vai de 1 á 5, mas de 0 á 4.
Ao fazer `return vetorC[5];` a sexta posição será buscada e como ela não existe, a exceção `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` é lançada.

O correto seria `return vetorC[4];`, mas como esse trecho será removido, o problema será removido também.

---

Dica: no método `somaValores()` não "force" até onde seu `for` deve ir. Use o tamanho do array como parâmetro. Veja:

Ao invés de fazer assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Faça assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
```

Como já é feito no método `inserirValores()`.

Comment: Obrigado pelas considerações Igor. Mas se eu coloco "return VetorC." Ele dá o mesmo erro **int[] cannot converted to int**, acredito porque se o vetorC é vetorC[], não posso mesmo pedir para retorná-lo como vetorC apenas. O tamanho do vetor, até usei com length antes, mas ele estoura do mesmo jeito e como a minha variável "i" iniciar em zero, ele está dentro do tamanho de 5 posições.

Comment: @LuisFernando desculpe. Atualizei a resposta. Faça `return vetorC[];`

Comment: rs, já tentei também, ai aparece: .class expected / Unexpected type: required: value, found class;

Comment: @LuisFernando voltei a resposta para o que era anteriormente. O que comentei está errado. Estou tentando entender o que está acontecendo.. vc alterou o tipo de retorno? qual linha da o erro?